# Peakedness of multimodal distributions

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

In Probability theory, does there exist some measures of peaked-ness for multi-modal distributions. I guess kurtosis as such would not be a good measure of peaked-ness for multimodal distributions. Please correct me if I am wrong. Can you point me to some of them which are simpler to compute.

Answer (score 3):

What about [information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29)?  The smaller it is, the more mass is in peaks.